# Reusing view on different scenes in IB or programatically

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, interface-builder

I've a view which I want to reuse on other scenes in IB. This view contains user details such as name, avatar, description, few buttons etc. These views are exactly same and have same elements inside them. Right now it's pain to copy them across scenes, fix the constraints and then code the same elements over and over again. It's not quite productive and it's time consuming. Ideally I want to see these views on IB so I don't want to code do everything programmatically without any visual. Is there a way we can make it in better way so that I can just reuse it?

Comment: Create a separate view class, create a xib for it and put the view into every view controller you need?

Answer (score 0):

Not only is it pain, it is poor design to rebuild the same component. I would create a xib file, create the backing swift or obj-c files. Wire up all the outlets as you would normally.

In each view controller or view that you need it, initialize it and add it as a subview.

In swift, I would do something like:

```
if let subview = Bundle.main.loadNibNamded("SpecialView", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as SpecialView {

    // set constraints
    containerView.addSubView(subview)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. I've done this recently. I started in a `VC` that was a child of a `NavigationController` and pushed a view onto the view stack that was outside of the `NavigationController`'s scope so the new view did not have the `NavigationBar` up top.

Assuming you are using a storyboard, you'll create the view with all of it's actions and outlets and link them up to its own class file. Also give the storyboarded view an ID. Then you need to define the controller as a constant and push it to your view stack when you want it used.

```
 // define the controller
 let controller = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "YourCustomControllerID") as! YourCustomController

 // if you want to pass data to the new controller 
 // first you must define some class variables in that class then you do this: 
 controller.image = whateverImage 

 // then you push it to the stack like this
 self.navigationController!.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
```

To dismiss that view, you call `dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)` in `YourCustomController`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are a few.

Custom views are loaded as cnbecom said, using LoadNibNamed. Owner is a proxy class, meaning it just represents "anything". Owner is like a connection that is fitted but not made until you create the class, if that makes sense.

Another method is to create the custom view in code, but instead of having a separate nib, you just re-create the view and change the type in the main Xib/Container Xib. You will have to copy/paste the nib, and that's made easier by embedding it into a view before copying. Even with constraints, this method is easier. Hook up the outlets in the containing Xib.

Third is pure code. This is one primary reason constraints are just extra work, no benefits.

Fourth, is to load the Nib but inside a container. Basically it loads itself into its own type via the AwakeFromNib method. You then have to hook up the outlets to the inner Xib realizing that Owner changed. This method is useful if you can visualize what is inside the white square.

Also I never use constraints. The few times it would be helpful, it's still faster to write a basic single-line of frame x,y code in layoutSubviews or similar. Custom views and manually using layoutSubviews will save you lots of time. Springs and struts are extremely powerful, and iOS lacks the CSS media queries for full layout-changes, just has ways to move constraints around (which modifies existing layout, not helpful if changing menu entirely for two different device types).

Create different xibs for tablet, then write a loading func that tests if on tablet and appends a prefix, will give you an amazing system once you get custom loading down.

Anyway, enjoy! I believe this question is a slight duplicate, as your marker was the frustration with auto-layout, but your real question is "How do I load custom views in Swift", which has been answered many.

Comment: "I never use constraints". huh, terrible advice.

Comment: Why is it terrible advice? Do you like taking extra hours to accomplish the same thing?

Comment: The other way around. I took the time 5 years ago to learn constraints properly and realized they are more powerful than autoresizing. That's why they were introduced. If you know what to do, they are always faster to create than manual layout, especially in Interface Builder, and you don't have to bother about magic constants (offset, spacings) in code. Not only that, they provide better performance during layout.

Comment: I studied Erica Sadun's book and compared it to overriding a couple frame layouts, although I always create my own stack and wrapping views. Plus, they don't slow down scrollViews (unsure how you haven't ran into that). Anyway, if you happen to want to share the xib or a screenshot/example of exactly what you were doing to make all those constants, if I can't figure out a way to reduce the code, then I suppose I'll learn something. Otherwise, I'll show you how to reduce it, if you are able to/desire to go that far

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to that:

1. Programatically (or writing code might be involved)
   create a custom view and include all the interface setup you need including the data and add it to each controller you want it to be shown
2. Take the advantage of `Container view` for loading the other content in another controller as in this [Github repo](https://github.com/omiz/Reusable-View-Example)

Here is what I did in the second example:

- Create a base controller that holds the view that I want to always be shown
- Add a view and customize it as required
- Add a `Container View` in the same controller
- Add a `NavigationController` and embed it in the `Container View`

[image]